# Weblogic can't deploy EJB project

Tags: java, jpa, jakarta-ee, ejb, weblogic

### Here is Error

```
Error is: "weblogic.management.DeploymentException:<strong>java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.persistence.AttributeConverter"
weblogic.management.DeploymentException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.persistence.AttributeConverter</strong>
at weblogic.application.internal.BaseDeployment.throwAppException(BaseDeployment.java:123)
at    weblogic.application.internal.BaseDeployment.activate(BaseDeployment.java:260)
at weblogic.application.internal.EarDeployment.activate(EarDeployment.java:61)
at weblogic.application.internal.DeploymentStateChecker.activate(DeploymentStateChecker.java:165)
at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.AppContainerInvoker.activate(AppContainerInvoker.java:80)
Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
Caused By: 
 <strong>java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.persistence.AttributeConverter
at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.findLocalClass(GenericClassLoader.java:335)
at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.findClass(GenericClassLoader.java:302)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:423)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:356)
at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.loadClass(GenericClassLoader.java:180)
Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace </strong>
weblogic.management.DeploymentException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.persistence.AttributeConverter
at weblogic.application.internal.BaseDeployment.throwAppException(BaseDeployment.java:123)
at weblogic.application.internal.BaseDeployment.activate(BaseDeployment.java:260)
at weblogic.application.internal.EarDeployment.activate(EarDeployment.java:61)
at weblogic.application.internal.DeploymentStateChecker.activate(DeploymentStateChecker.java:165)
at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.AppContainerInvoker.activate(AppContainerInvoker.java:80)
Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
Caused By: <strong>java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.persistence.AttributeConverter
at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.findLocalClass(GenericClassLoader.java:335)
at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.findClass(GenericClassLoader.java:302)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:423)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:356)
at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.loadClass(GenericClassLoader.java:180)
Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace</strong>
```

Comment: Could you edit the quest ion to explain how you got to this problem and what you tried to solve it?

Comment: I find problem is same as ear package name to new one  confilct to old one ,you can see console log :<Warning> <Deployer> <BEA-149007> <New source location, "D:\WebLoans\WebAppTest\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.core.resources\.projects\LoansApp\beadep\base_domain3\LoansApp", cannot be deployed to the configured application, "LoansApp". The application source is at "F:\eclipse_mars_space\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.core.resources\.projects\LoansApp\beadep\base_domain3\LoansApp\split_src". Changing the source location is not allowed for a previously attempted deployment.

Answer (score 0):

You need JPA API v2.1 jar and you don't have it in the CLASSPATH of the JavaEE server (or you have v2.0 or v1.0). ClassNotFoundException can't get simpler.

Comment: Yes ,Project use jpa 2.1.

Comment: And Yes Project cannot see jpa 2.1 at runtime so Project gets ClassNotFoundException.

Comment: I think so, problem isn't we watched

Comment: How to delete old ear package on Weblogic.